# Unable to load variables in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a following code :

```
sess = tf.Session()
model_file = './runs/1488368349/checkpoints/model-42200.meta'
checkpoint_dir = './runs/1488368349/checkpoints/'


new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(model_file)
#new_saver.restore(sess, MODEL_PATH)
new_saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint(checkpoint_dir))

all_vars = tf.get_collection('vars')
print len(all_vars)
for v in all_vars:
        v_ = sess.run(v)
        print(v_)
```

But the above code is unable to load variables. I am getting the length of all_vars as 0.
Can someone tell me what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.VARIABLES)
```

This should give you all trainable and untrainable variables...